# One time gives exception another time doesnt

Tags: c#, multithreading, out-of-memory

I use multi threading to copy file to another place.I from stream needed byte array and dispose stream.at this example i use 7 threads to copy 3gb file.1st thread can get byte array,but at 2nd thread occurs exception 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

```
public void Begin()
{
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open);
    stream.Position = (threNmb - 1) * 536870912;
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    for (long i = 0; i < (length); i++)
    {
        source.Add(reader.ReadByte());//gives exception at i=134217728
    }
    reader.Dispose();
    reader.Close();
    stream.Dispose();
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: What's the exception? Any reason for not using `using` statements? Generally it's a bad idea to use multiple threads for IO to a single disk anyway - you're just forcing it to thrash. The biggest performance improvement you could achieve here would quite possibly be to read chunks of data at a time instead of lots of calls to `ReadByte`.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you've got an `OutOfMemoryException`. What's the type of `source`? (I do hope you're not using a simple `List<T>` from multiple threads concurrently...)

Comment: yes,i use List<byte> ,i dont know i have other way or not,i used byte[] but it is not big as i want

Comment: See my answer - what are you doing with the list afterwards, exactly?

Comment: Really? 3GB in a List<byte> ?

Comment: i have own progress bar which is TextBlock shown copy process:like this "##--#-####--#--" (# is completed,- not completed).I show each thread process as 10 of "-".For this i need to count and when it is 1/10 of then raise event to change "-" to #"

Comment: @Erno in 7 thread(7 List<byte>)

Comment: I am new at programming my chief give me it to improve my working skills at multi threading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a `List<byte>`. That's going to be a very inefficient way of copying data, and you're probably making it *less* efficient by using multiple threads. Additionally, if you're using a single list from multiple threads, your code is already broken - `List<T>` isn't thread-safe. Even if it were, you'd be mixing the data from the different threads, so you wouldn't be able to reassemble the original data. Oh, and by not using `using` statements, if an exception *is* thrown you're leaving file handles open. In other words, I'm advising you to completely abandon your current approach.

Instead, copying a file from one place to another (assuming you can't use [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) for some reason),  should basically be a case of:

- Open stream to read
- Open stream to write
- Allocate buffer (e.g. 32K)
- Repeatedly:

  - Read from the "input" stream into the buffer, noting how much data the call actually read
  - Write the data you've just read into the output stream
  - Loop until your "Read" indicates the end of the input stream
- Close both streams (with `using` statements)

There's no need to have everything in memory. Note that in .NET 4 this is made even easier with the [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) method. which does the third and fourth steps for you.

Comment: but when i use stream to read and  copy to other place,other threads willn't be able to use file to copy other parts,what to do ?

Comment: @cavidanquliyev: As I've explained, you shouldn't be using multiple threads to copy a single file anyway - it'll just cause the disk to thrash. Have you *tried* the simple approach and found it to be too slow? You *could* potentially use asynchronous IO and be reading from input at the same time as writing to output, but I personally wouldn't do that until after I'd proved the above approach was too slow.